# For each module that have two or more registered students, display their ModuleID, MName and the total number of registered students for the module

Tags: sql, oracle

[Link to Schema for Question](https://www.scribd.com/document/358343499/DBDI-Relational-Schema-Data)I am getting through with the first part which is to display the moduleID and name of the modules who have 2 or more registered students but the second part where you are showing how much student is registered for that module im not getting through with it

SQL I tried:

```
SELECT moduleid, 
       mname, 
       Count(moduleid) 
FROM   module 
GROUP  BY moduleid, 
          mname 
HAVING moduleid IN(SELECT moduleid 
                   FROM   registration 
                   GROUP  BY moduleid 
                   HAVING Count (moduleid) >= 2)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Ok I added a link to for the data that I am using

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is standard question to check knowledge of `group by` and `having`, both are widely supported by RDBMS's.

Comment: @przemo_li: still: some DBMS show strange behaviour even with the most basic syntax. And some DBMS even lack very basic features (I do agree in this case it doesn't really make a difference, but still...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming that there is some `studentid` which identifies students in the `registration` table:

```
SELECT moduleid, 
       mname, 
       Count(studentId) 
FROM   module m
JOIN   registration r
USING  ( moduleid)
GROUP  BY moduleid, 
          mname
HAVING Count(studentId)>=2
```

Comment: @Przemo_li I think all RDBMS exept some really reduced ones allow to have `HAVING` before **and** after GROUP BY clause, since this is a mandatory part of ANSII SQL Standard.